# Sort By with function on collection laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I would like some help on this, i have a table  like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `unitPrice` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalSold` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and after using `DB::table('items')->get();`
i would like to get the same result as if i run this sql command

```
"select `code`,(`unitPrice`*(`quantity`+`totalSold`)) as totalEarnIfsold from `items` order by `totalEarnIfsold` desc"
```

what i have been able to achieve without success ofc is this:

```
    $items_all->sortBy([
          $totalEarnIfsold=  fn ($a) => $a->unitPrice *($a->quantity+$a->totalSold),
          ['totalEarnIfsold', 'desc'],           
        ]);
```

So i need your help if you may ofc, and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in following way

**First you need to calculate totalEarnIfsold with map function and after that you can easily sort with value.**

```
$items_all = $items_all->map(function($item) {
        $item->totalEarnIfsold = $item->unitPrice *($item->quantity + $item->totalSold);
        return $item;
        })->sortByDesc('totalEarnIfsold');
```